# How to call CSS from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to have different background images for different conditions (JS,HTML,CSS). For E.g: if(n=1),then image 1
else if(n=2),then image 2 etc.

Comment: Have you tried to do this? Could you show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty easy in jQuery.

```
if(n == 1){
     $('your_image_element').css('background-image','url(your_first_img_path)') ;
}else if(n ==2){
      // second image...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a **Css class** ..After that you can set it to your control from javascript..

```
document.getElementById("MyControl").className = "MyClass";
```

In the css class **MyClass** you can set the background image..You can create another css class with different background image and set it according to the conditions..

Answer (score 1):

Once you have picked the object you are manipulating, you can set its css properties directly from the script. E.g for the background image change on the body element:

```
var object = document.body;
object.style.backgroundImage="url('new_image.jpg')";
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use script to dynamically change a CSS rule, e.g.

```
var image;

if ( /*some condition */ ) {
  image = 'a.png';
}  else {
  image = 'b.png';
}

document.write('<style type="text/css">.someClass {background-image:url("' + image + '");}<\/style>');
```

Of course there are more sophisticated ways to modify the rule, the above is just a basic method.